# Trying to connect to VM VirtualBox MySQL from Windows 7 using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench

I am trying to save myself some time and eye strain by connecting my to MySQL on my VM (Ubuntu 14.04)

I have a bridged connection set up, and I test my web applications on my windows by simply navigating to `http://ip_of_vm/application/index.php`, so I know that they are communicating. However, when I tried setting up the connection in MySQL Workbench, I come to a screeching halt. Here are my connection parameters:

```
Hostname: ip_of_vm
Port: 3306 (Default)
Username: tim -> Which is a user created on my VM using: CREATE USER 'tim'@'%' in MySQL
Password: **** -> No I'm not going to paste my password here.
Default Schema: test_database
```

But when I press test connection I get this error:

Failed to connect to MySQL at ip_of_vm with user tim.
Can't connect to MySQL server on ip_of_vm (10061)

I've tried searching for that error code and making some adjustments based on what I've found, but I'm still having no luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you `GRANT ALL`...?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Yes, granted all privileges on *.* to tim@%